# onclick não funciona com método importado de módulo

Tags: javascript, onclick

Tenho um projetinho que usa HTML e Javascript onde eu preencho um formulário e ao acionar um botão, o Javascript pega as informações do formulário e cria um objeto que logo em seguida mostra as informações digitadas no formulário no log.

O problema é que ao acionar o botão o seguinte erro aparece no console do navegador:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: criarEvento is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Aqui está o código:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Teste </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    Tipo:<input id="tipo" type="text"><br>
    Data:<input id="data" type="text"><br>
    Valor:<input id="valor" type="text"><br>

    <select id="status">
      <option value="1"> Ativo </option>
      <option value="2"> Inativo </option>

    </select><br>

    <input type="button" value="Criar" onclick="criarEvento()">
  </form>

</body>
<script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

main.js

```js
import { Evento } from "./eventos.js"


function criarEvento() {
  let tipoA = document.getElementById('tipo').value
  let dataA = document.getElementById('data').value
  let valorA = document.getElementById('valor').value
  let statusA = document.getElementById('status').value
  const evento1 = new Evento(tipoA, dataA, valorA, statusA)

  evento1.mostrarDados()
}
```

eventos.js

```js
class Evento {
  constructor(tipo, data, valor, status) {
    this.tipo = tipo
    this.data = data
    this.valor = valor
    this.status = status
  }

  mostrarDados() {
    console.log("Tipo: " + this.tipo)
    console.log("Tipo: " + this.data)
    console.log("Tipo: " + this.valor)
    console.log("Tipo: " + this.tipo)
  }
}

export { Evento }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O modulo importado tem um escopo próprio, por isso o método `criarEvento` não está acessível em index.html. Uma alternativa é adicionar o evento ao botão no próprio main.js usando [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
document.querySelector('form input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', criarEvento)
```

Comment: Ajudou demais man !! Valeuzão